# Heroku deployment with Git fails with 504 Gateway TImeout

Tags: git, heroku, deployment

Due to the recent problems on Heroku´s Dashboard, I am trying to deploy directly my app through Git as stated here:  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#deploy-your-code

Running the following command:
`git push heroku main`

produces the following output:

```
Enumerating objects: 11344, done.
Counting objects: 100% (11344/11344), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (9862/9862), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11344/11344), 1.44 GiB | 210.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 11344 (delta 1833), reused 9874 (delta 1353), pack-reused 0
```

After a long time the deployment fails due to the following error:

```
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 504
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have already tried to increase the postBuffer in case it helped but to no avail:

`git config http.postBuffer 2147483648`

The slug size of my previous deployment after compression is 121M, which should not be either a problem, since the changes I have made are minimal.

I dont know, I have always deployed manually through Heroku´s Dashboard, but now I ve been a week without being able to do itand I am running out of ideas other than waiting for the features to be restored, which seems to take long. Any ideas would be really appreciated

Comment: Please run `git remote -v` and show the result.

Comment: ```heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myherokuappname.git (fetch)

   heroku  https://git.heroku.com/myherokuappname.git (push)

 origin  https://github.com/myusername/mygithubrepo.git (fetch)
 
 origin  https://github.com/myusername/mygithubrepo.git (push)
 
staging git@heroku.com:myherokuappname.git (fetch)
 
staging git@heroku.com:myherokuappname.git (push)```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem deploying after the Heroku/Github dashboard was disabled and swapped to the Heroku-CLI.

You apparently need to specify which branch you are pushing from even when pushing from "main" *and* which remote heroku branch to push too (also main)

For example, to deploy code to Heroku from a **non-main** branch of your local repository (for example, testbranch), you'd use the following syntax push it to the remote’s main branch:

```
git push heroku testbranch:main
```

It usually defaults but now we have to specify main/master

TL;DR
You can fix it with:

```
git push heroku main:main
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately the problem stays the same even if I tried your solution